# PDO bindValue() is not binding

Tags: php, ajax, json, pdo, bindvalue

The idea of the following script is to add or remove a date to / from a datebase based on the user clicking on a date in the jQuery UI datepicker calendar which I have set up to pick up the date clicked.

I am sending a jQuery.post() to a php page that contains the following code.

The issue is that the value I pick up in the $_POST[] variable will not bind to the PDO->prepare statement and I end up just adding 0000-00-00 to my database!

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_date'])) {
$edit_date = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['edit_date']), ENT_QUOTES);

require_once '../includes/db_cnx.include.php';

// Check if already exists
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dates` WHERE `date` = :date");
$query->bindValue(':date', $edit_date);
print_r($query);
$query->execute();

$num_rows = $query->rowCount();
echo '(num rows: ' . $num_rows . ')';
if ($num_rows === 0 ) {
    // INSERT NEW
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `dates` (`date`) VALUES (:insert_date)");
    $query->bindValue(':insert_date', $edit_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    print_r($query);
    $query->execute();
    if ($query->rowCount() === 1) {
        $return_msg = 'Date added to database';
    } else {
        $return_msg = 'Could not add date to database';
    }
} else if ($num_rows === 1) {
    // DELETE EXISTING
    $query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `dates` WHERE `date` = :delete_date");
    $query->bindValue(':delete_date', $edit_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    print_r($query);
    $query->execute();
    if ($query->rowCount() === 1) {
        $return_msg = 'Date removed from database';
    } else {
        $return_msg = 'Date could not be removed from database';
    }
} else {
    // error??
    $return_msg = 'More than one entry for this date. Please contact the administrator';
}

echo $return_msg . '- ' . $edit_date;
```

}

If I output the received $_POST['edit_date'] I see the correct value (e.g. 2013-03-01).

If I output the SELECT statement after binding I see:

```
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT * FROM `dates` WHERE `date` = :date
)
```

Does this mean it has not bound the actual value to :date ?

Even seeing the above showing :date it does seem to be doing its job as I get the correct number of rows back based on whether it found the date or not.

Based on the number of returned rows it then drops into the correct if / else block. But will then show me for example:

```
(
    [queryString] => INSERT INTO `dates` (`date`) VALUES (:insert_date)
)
```

And I input the 0000-00-00 date as mentioned above.

It's begining to drive me round the bend !

Is it binding even though it's not showing me in the output?
And if it is why is it using 000-00-00 rather than my actual values?

Thank you!

EDIT...
In case it is helpful the jquery post from the other page looks like this:

```
onSelect: function(){
          var day = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();
          var month = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;
          var year = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
          var fullDate = year + " - " + month + " - " + day;

          $.post('admin_functions.php', {"edit_date" : fullDate}, function (data) {
            alert(data);
          });
      }
```

Comment: Why is there a `$edit_date = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['edit_date']), ENT_QUOTES);` at top?

Comment: I am just storing the $_POST variable in my own variable so that I don't have to refer to the $_POST value directly each time. Plus I take that opportunity to "clean" the value for any sql injection attempt. I understood this was common practice? Is it not? - I'd assumed it was less work as it doesn't have to check the server sent value everytime and so save resources.

Comment: Just to be safe, could you output the result of `var_dump($edit_date);` right before you bind the value to make sure there are no other characters that would cause mysql to not recognize the date?

Comment: The var_dump gives me: string(12) "2013 - 3 - 1"

Comment: And there's your result. How are you passing this `edit_date` variable?

Comment: I dont understand. What's the result? Do you mean its something to do with the double quotes? I'm passing it from a jQuery .post. I will add the script to the original question if you think that will help.

Comment: Just to check I just removed the htmlspecialchars(trim()) from the $_POST varaible and got the same output from var_dump($edit_date) so am not sure that is related ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date variable contains `2013 - 3 - 1`, mysql nor php will be able to recognize it as a valid date.

Assuming that you are using a date field in mysql, you need to feed it a date in the format: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

The easiest way to solve your problem, is to remove the spaces that you are adding in your javascript so that your date becomes `2013-3-1`. Now php can recognize it and you can use:

```
$date_for_sql = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['edit_date']));
```

There are of course other (and more robust...) solutions to verify that you have a valid date, you can explode on the `-` to get the components, etc.

Comment: Brilliant!!!!  So I've been looking in the wrong bloody place all along!? Story of my life. Accepted this answer due to the suggestion of PHP strtotime() rather than @Dream Eater's MySQL STR_TO_DATE() which is maybe ever-so-slightly cleaner bearing in mind PDO and trying to stay database independent and all that! But thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery code, change the following:

```
var fullDate = year + " - " + month + " - " + day;
```

to

```
var fullDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

**NOTICE:** No extra spaces being passed.

Then, in your insert query, use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse string as date. And your preparation statement shall be:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `dates` (`date`) 
    VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(:insert_date, '%Y-%c-%e'))");
```